# GLTF animations result in distorted mesh

Tags: c#, gltf

I've downloaded the GLTF sample Fox https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/Fox
and been trying to get the animations working through SharpGLTF.

So far it looks fine when pass in the joint worldTransform * inverseBindMatrix
[image]

But when trying the first frame of the animation looks all distorted
[image]

Here is the code that calculates the bone transformations. I hope anyone knows what might be wrong, I've been trying to get it to work for 3 days and don't know where to look anymore.

```cs
private void UpdateBone (Node node, Matrix4x4 parentTransformation) {
    Skin skin = skeleton.skin;
    (Node joint, System.Numerics.Matrix4x4 inverseBindMatrix) = skin.GetJoint(0);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < skin.JointsCount; i++) {
        (joint, inverseBindMatrix) = skin.GetJoint(i);
        if (joint.Name == node.Name) break;
    }

    
    Matrix4x4 scale = Matrix4x4.Identity;
    Matrix4x4 rotation = Matrix4x4.Identity;
    Matrix4x4 translation = Matrix4x4.Identity;
    IEnumerable<AnimationChannel> jointChannels = currentAnimation.logicalAnimation.FindChannels(joint);
    foreach (var jointChannel in jointChannels) {
        if (jointChannel.GetTranslationSampler() is { } translationSampler) {
            translation = Matrix4x4.Translation(Vector3.FromSystemVector(translationSampler.GetLinearKeys().First().Value));
        }

        if (jointChannel.GetRotationSampler() is { } rotationSampler) {
            rotation = Matrix4x4.RotationQuaternion((Quaternion) rotationSampler.GetLinearKeys().First().Value);
        }

        if (jointChannel.GetScaleSampler() is { } scaleSampler) {
            scale = Matrix4x4.Scaling(Vector3.FromSystemVector(scaleSampler.GetLinearKeys().First().Value));
        }
    }

    Matrix4x4 localTransformation = translation * rotation * scale;
    Matrix4x4 globalTransformation = parentTransformation * localTransformation;
    skeletonState.BoneTransformations[node.LogicalIndex] = Matrix4x4.Identity;
    
    foreach (var child in node.VisualChildren) {
        if (child is null || !child.IsSkinJoint) continue;
        
        UpdateBone(child, globalTransformation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no need to compose the animations myself in SharpGLTF. Here is the helpful message from VPenades on the SharpGLTF Discord

> node.GetLocalTransform(Animation, Time);  and
> node.GetWorldTransform(Animation, Time);  depending on which one you
> need, are the ones that give you the animated transforms you need to
> update your bones, you don't need all that code.
>
> but these calls are fairly slow, they're there for convenience, but the fast way is to use node.GetCurveSamplers once, and reuse it to get the matrices

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the project on Github https://github.com/vpenades/SharpGLTF
There is no documentation as far I can find unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It seems that correct matrix operation is:
m0i * m0 * bindm * m

where m0i is inverse of m0 matrix, m0 is the matrix collected from the tree (without animations applied), bindm is the bind matrix, and m is the slerped matrix collected from the tree with animations applied.

(but I'm actually using ri * m0i * m0 * bindm * m * resize, where ri and resize are there to resize the model correctly)